# Trying to make sure that no more than one instance of an email exists in ASP.Net. Is there a better way of doing this?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, mongodb, validation, mongodb-query

I'm try to query the database for all shoppers that have a certain email to stop the server from creating shoppers with duplicate emails. If the query is empty then it means that the server can go ahead and create the new shopper. The problem is that my solution is based around the function throwing the exception `System.Linq.ThrowHelper.ThrowNoElementsException()` Please see the following code:

```
public async Task<Shopper?> GetByEmailAsync(string email)
{
     try
     {
         var shopper = await _shoppersCollection.Find(x => x.Email == email).FirstAsync();
         return shopper;
     }
     catch (System.Exception e)
     {
         return null;
     }
}
```

This function is called in the following function:

```
async public Task<Boolean> ValidateEmail(string email)
{
    var shopperWithEmail = await GetByEmailAsync(email);

    if (shopperWithEmail == null)
    {
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

That function is used in this function in the controller to validate the given email:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Post(Shopper newShopper)
{
    if (await _shoppersService.ValidateEmail(newShopper.Email)!)
        return StatusCode(409, new { message = "Email is already in use." });

    await _shoppersService.CreateAsync(newShopper);

    return CreatedAtAction(nameof(Get), new { id = newShopper.Id }, newShopper);
}
```

My point is that if feel like my implementation is bad; there has to be a better to solve this than to catch an exception, as I was taught that it is bad practice. I've searched the internet with no avail and couldn't decipher the docs. Any suggestions are appreciated, even if just general tips and not strictly relevant to the question.

Thank you.

Comment: '_to stop the server from creating shoppers with duplicate emails_' - sounds like you're looking to create a [unique index](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/index-unique/) (and the app code should check the response when it attempts the insert so that it can respond appropriately to the request from the user)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write the first method like this.

```
public async Task<Shopper?> GetByEmailAsync(string email)
{
     
    return await _shoppersCollection.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Email == email);
    
}
```

Therefore, there is no need to add `try` `catch` block. Because FirstOrDefaultAsync() will return null if there is no Shopper with given email.

And my suggestion is to change the second method so it makes more sense.

```
async public Task<Boolean> IsEmailInUse(string email)
{
    var shopper = await GetByEmailAsync(email);
    
    return shopper == null ? false : true;
}
```

Rest of the code:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Post(Shopper newShopper)
{
    if (!await _shoppersService.IsEmailInUse(newShopper.Email)!)
        return StatusCode(409, new { message = "Email is already in use." });

    await _shoppersService.CreateAsync(newShopper);

    return CreatedAtAction(nameof(Get), new { id = newShopper.Id }, newShopper);
}
```

Comment: Fantastic! That's exactly what I was looking to do can couldn't find the right function for it. As for the sloppy code, I realized just as I made this post that it was a disaster. Anyway, thank you very much!

Comment: Another option is to use "Any" if you want to just return the boolean of where there are any emails that match the email you have in the list.  

`return await _shoppersCollection.Any(x => x.Email == email);`

Comment: @jeffsdata, I agree with you, I forgot about using `Any` which would simplify the code and reduce it to a single line. If the `_shoppersCollection` is accessible in the controller, there may not be a need for additional methods to abstract the code